# Run gitlab-ci for another project

Tags: github, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-api

We have a application which is managed by third-party. They use Github to store source code. My company now use Gitlab for internal project. We setup Gitlab mirror to pull source code (incl branch: dev, stagging, master) from Github. It's working well now.

Now my manager want to setup Gitlab pipeline for automation process: build, test, deploy...I do it by commit .gitlab-ci.yml file to branch. But it's not good. After Gitlab pull code from Gitlab, it will overwrite my gitlab-ci file and remove it. So I must find another solution

Below is my idea now:

- Create seperate project. It only contains gitlab-ci file
- Detect changes on any branch in mirror repo
- Trigger pipeline

Anyone has other idea for this case, please help me

P/S: third-party don't agree to add my gitlab-ci file into their repo in Github.